# DevExpress TextEdit on validation error freezes and doesn't move until error corrected

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I use DevExpress TextEdit. I have Validate event there I set the Validation error. But once the error is set, it doesn't allow the cursor to be moved to other control and gives the impression that the UI has been frozen, until the error has been corrected. How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use InvalidValueBehavior="AllowLeaveEditor"